# What is the replacement of mod operator?

Tags: c

I have a code segment that requires the remainder of two ints. I am using modulus operator as usual but I am hearing that it takes more time. So I am asking that is there any way to get the remainder more efficiently  than mod operation...
The following will be my code

```
int rem=gid%bpp
```

`gid` being any int and `bpp` being 2,4,8,16,32.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears from your question that `bpp` is always a power of 2, in which case you can use instead:

```
int rem = gid & (bpp - 1);
```

However you should not optimise prematurely - unless you have profiled and know for certain that this mod operation is a bottleneck then you should just leave it in its original, more readable form.